# class "SimpleXml" not found, EC2 server issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, amazon-ec2, simplexml

My project is in EC2, upon delete any s3 file I am having this error.
(1/1) FatalThrowableError Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found

I have PHP 7.2 and XML and SimpleXML both installed in EC2. my local server does not throw this error while deleting from s3.
Here is the codebase

```php
public function delete($memory_id) {
    $memory = new Memory();
    $qaMemory = new MemoryAccess;       
    $memoryInfo = $memory->where('memory_id',$memory_id)->first();
    $qaMemory->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->where('memory_recall_datetime',$memoryInfo->recall_date)->first();
    $qaMemory->delete();
    if($memoryInfo->mime_type) {
        $path = $memoryInfo->memory_content;
        $pathArray = explode('/', $path);
        if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists(end($pathArray))) { // error occoured
            $isDeleted =  Storage::disk('s3')->delete(end($pathArray));
        } else {
            //echo "not found";
        }
    }
    $memory->delete();

    return redirect('home')->with('registration_success', 'Registration successful');
}
```

I have the SimpleXML package installed on EC2
here image of the extensions loaded in php7.2 on EC2:

[image]

can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: How do you run your script? In the browser? You know that the PHP configuration on the shell (which you gathered through `php -m`) and for the webserver are done in different files?

Comment: In the browser. phpinfo() shows libxml is active. this issue is in EC2. PHP version is 7.2.

Comment: restarting php-fcm helps.